# How do I supress date/time display in GNU Screen vertical splits?

Tags: unix, terminal, gnu-screen, terminal-emulator

I am using a copy of GNU Screen packaged for Fedora 18.

I copied [these neat lines](http://www.karan.org/blog/index.php/2010/01/06/this-is-my-screenrc-whats-yours) over onto my `.screenrc`, to show me the host/date-time/windows:

```
# Neat status bar on the bottom of the screen
caption string "%?%F%{= Bk}%? %C%A %D %d-%m-%Y %{= kB} %t%= %?%F%{= Bk}%:%{= wk}%? %n "
hardstatus alwayslastline
hardstatus string '%{= kG}[ %{G}%H %{g}][%= %{= kw}%?%-Lw%?%{r}(%{W}%n*%f%t%?(%u)%?%{r})%{w}%?%+Lw%?%?%= %{g}][%{B} %d/%m %{W}%c %{g}]'
```

Occasionally, I fire up a vertical split (`Ctrl a - |`), and this causes another status bar stacked on top of the window status bar I've got. This new status bar shows the date-time/window-name/window-number for each split. Now the date-time is a useless distraction. I would rather just see the window identification and nothing else for each vertical split.

How can I supress display of the date-time on the vertical split statuses?

If you want to see what I mean, here is a screenshot. Look at line#2 from the bottom of the screen:

[image: A screenshot of GNU Screen running two vertical splits]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what you get for copying neat lines instead of understanding them, especially because these already look like quite the catastrophic result of too much copying...

- `hardstatus alwayslastline`
  This means that you want the line defined as "hardstatus" to always be displayed, and you want it to fill the last line of your terminal.
- `hardstatus string <stuff>`
  This means you're defining what the "hardstatus" line should look like. For details, read the [String Escapes](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/String-Escapes.html) explanation; I'll start you off:

  - **`%{= kG}`** The **colour** (`${}`) is **set** (`=`) to black back- and light green foreground (`kG`)
  - **`[_`** a literal square bracket and space are printed,
  - **`%{G}%H_`** the **colour** (`%{}`) is again(!?) set to light green foreground (`G`), then the current **hostname** is printed (`%H`), followed by a literal space
  - **`%{g}][`** the **colour** (`%{}`) is set to dark green foreground (`g`), followed by close-bracket and open-bracket
  - **`%=_`** elastic **padding**, followed by a literal space (this guarantees at least one space)
  - **`%{= kw}`** the **colour** (`%{}`) is **set** (`=`) to white-on-black (`kw`)
  - **`%?%-Lw%?`** this one's interesting, needs to be read inside-out: the **list of window names** (`%w`), if applicable **with flags** (`L`), but only for window numbers **less than the current one** (`-`); this list is only printed **if there is a non-empty expansion** (`%?`..`%?` for "if" and "endif"), which makes no sense here, because there's nothing besides the single exansion, which is otherwise empty anyway.
  - **`%{r}`** change the **colour** (`%{}`) to **red foreground** (`r`)

  ... and so on, you get the idea. It contains multiple pointless elements, including the last conditional (which is both unnecessary and not explicitly closed).

  - `caption string <stuff>`
    This sets a special "caption", which will be displayed as the last line of every region. You can choose for this to be always displayed or just if you have splits (default) with `caption always` or `caption splitonly`; you cannot disable it, but you can set it to an empty string. I'll call out the initial conditional, which is useful:
  - **`%?%F%{= Bk}%?`**
    The `%F` means "do this if the current region is active, even if no escape sequence expands to printable characters". The `%{= Bk}` sets the color to black ("k") on light blue.

Anyway. What you want to do is change that caption; you say you only want "the window identification for each vertical split"; I'll assume you're fine with the colour highlighting. I'd use these, all fixed up:

```
hardstatus alwayslastline '%{= kG}[ %H ]%{g}[%= %{w}%-Lw%{r}(%{W}%n*%f%t%?(%u)%?%{r})%{w}%+Lw%= %{g}]%{G}[%{B} %d/%m %{W}%c %{G}]'
caption splitonly '%?%F%{= BW}%:%{= kg}%? %t %='
```